# Can't validate HTML content if it contains < and > characters with DOMParser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to build an HTML editor validator in Javascript.

Here is the JS code that checks if the HTML inserted by the user is valid or not:

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString('<html>' + myHTML + '</html>', 'application/xml');
let errorNode = doc.querySelector('parsererror');
if (errorNode) {
  return 'HTML is not valid';
} else {
  return 'HTML is valid';
}
```

**Example that returns "HTML is valid":  -> above code works as expected here**

```
<div>This HTML is valid</div>
```

**Example that returns "HTML is not valid":  -> above code works as expected here**

```
 <div>This HTML is not valid</divv>
```

Instead in these cases, my code doesn't work as I expected.
It considers "<" and ">" characters as HTML tag and then it returns error:

`<div> 2 < 3 </div>` -> **this is a valid HTML but above code returns "HTML is not valid".**

`<div> 4 > 3 </div>` -> **this is a valid HTML but above code returns "HTML is not valid".**

How should I go about it?

Comment: try using `'text/html'` mimetype since you want to parse html ...

Comment: `<div> 2 < 3 </div>` would be invalid HTML even in a source file, you've to write `<`s and `>`s in the text content as HTML entities, like `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call what `DOMParser.parseFromString()` does "validation"; rather, it applies HTML5's fallback parsing rules to reach a result -- any result -- that's hopefully consistent across browsers. Note `<html><div>...</div></html>` is **not** a valid, complete HTML document since at least a `<title>` element is required (as part of `<head>` which can be omitted) when the input to `parseFromString()` is supposed to be a complete document rather than a document fragment according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString. The whole story of HTML validation is way more complicated, and also depends on the version of HTML you're targeting. You can read about validating HTML using SGML on eg. https://validator.w3.org/docs/sgml.html, https://sgmljs.net/docs/parsing-html-tutorial/parsing-html-tutorial.html, and https://sgmljs.net/docs/html200129.html, and you can also check out [W3C's Java-based nu validator](https://github.com/validator/validator).

Anyway, to answer your question, try escaping (replacing) `<` characters by `&lt;` entity references.